# What would be the element of a matrix looks like if applying this?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider, $$C = ABA^T$$
Can $C_{ij}$, the element of $C$, be written in $B_{ij}$ and $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
C_{ij} = (ABA^T)_{ij} = \sum_{kl} A_{ik}B_{kl}A^{T}_{lj} = \sum_{kl}A_{ik}B_{kl}A_{lj}
$$